# Which Thread method are better use for keepalive thread?

Tags: android

I have a project that need Android device sync the Android Database Sqlite to server every 30 minutes, and i would like to create a thread to post the JSON to php page, and php page will insert/update the data into Server,
after i have read the Android official page about the thread article, Android suggest use 
**Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and FutureTask** thread, i need the thread keepalive until close the application

**Question : which thread method to use on this project? Please provide some example code**

This is the information i have found in Android official webs:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

`AsyncTask is designed to be a helper class around Thread and Handler and does not constitute a generic threading framework. AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time, it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the java.util.concurrent pacakge such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and FutureTask.`

Executor : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html

ThreadPoolExecutor : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

FutureTask : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html

Comment: Try using a service.. which do the work for you

Comment: @ViswanathL i have changed my question, i just want to sync when the Apps are running, not until the device shut down, so i would like to use thread. it is better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all android has inbuilt support for `Data Syncronization` Have a look at [Sync Adapters](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html). Try using this class which has inbuilt support for checking `Network Connectivity` and setup timer for running sync after fixed time, etc.

If you don't want to use that try manual way.

Handling a thread may become an overhead. You can use a `Service` which you can start on your app launch within `OnCreate` and destroy the service on `OnDestroy`. there are variety of service available that can communicate with the `UI` also. Have a look at [Android Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Why i sugguest service because , Sync has to be done in background that may take longer time period based on the `Network Speed` and `Server response`. So long Operations are easily handled with services.